# How to implement MergeSort on Linked List using only O(1) space?

Tags: java, linked-list, mergesort, space-complexity

How would one go about doing this? does the bottom-up mergesort way fulfill the `O(1)` extra space requirement? What is it in traditional mergesort that makes it not `O(1)` space?

Would this be a way?

```
void mergeSort() { 
    ListNode merge = this.head;
    this.head = mergeSort(merge);
}

ListNode mergeSort(ListNode head) {
    if(head == null || head.next == null)
        return head;

    ListNode slow = head; ListNode fast = head.next; 
    while(fast!=null && fast.next !=null) {
        slow = slow.next;
        fast = fast.next.next;
    }
    ListNode left = head; ListNode right = slow.next;
    slow.next = null;
    left = mergeSort(left);
    right = mergeSort(right);
    return merge(left, right);
}

ListNode merge(ListNode L, ListNode R) {
    if(L==null) return R;
    if(R==null) return L;
    ListNode h = null;
    if(L.val <= R.val )){
        h = L;
        h.next = merge(L.next, R);
    } else {
        h = R;
        h.next = merge(L, R.next);
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Merge sort a Linked List with O(nlogn) time and O(1) space complexity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43560711/how-to-merge-sort-a-linked-list-with-onlogn-time-and-o1-space-complexity)

Comment: You didn't specified the Language Java, C, C++?  The most important is the code that you can produce or the research that you can do. So we need that code to help you. Otherwise, it seem that you are asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please check these links to learn [How to write effective questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

A top down merge sort for linked list will consume O(log(n)) stack space, and it's slower than a bottom up approach due to scanning of lists to split them. The example code in the question will take O(n) stack space due to the recursive merge().

A bottom up merge sort for linked list uses a small (25 to 32) fixed size array of references (or pointers) to nodes, which would meet the O(1) space requirement. Link to wiki article. I can post example java code if interested.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists

Example java code:

```
    // merge two already sorted lists
    public ListNode merge(ListNode list0, ListNode list1) {
        if(list0 == null)
            return list1;
        if(list1 == null)
            return list0;
        ListNode temp = new ListNode(0);   // dummy node
        ListNode dest = temp;
        while(true){
            if(list0.element <= list1.element){
                dest.next = list0;
                dest = list0;
                list0 = list0.next;
                if(list0 == null){
                    dest.next = list1;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                dest.next = list1;
                dest = list1;
                list1 = list1.next;
                if(list1 == null){
                    dest.next = list0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return temp.next;
    }
    // sort list
    public ListNode sort(ListNode head) {
        final int NUMLIST = 32;
        ListNode[] alist = new ListNode[NUMLIST];
        ListNode node;
        ListNode next;
        int i;
        // if < 2 nodes, return
        if(head == null || head.next == null)
            return;
        node = head;
        // merge node into array
        while(node != null){
            next = node.next;
            node.next = null;
            for(i = 0; (i < NUMLIST) && (alist[i] != null); i++){
                node = merge(alist[i], node);
                alist[i] = null;
            }
            if(i == NUMLIST)   // don't go past end of array
                i--;
            alist[i] = node;
            node = next;
        }
        // node == null
        // merge array into single list
        for(i = 0; i < NUMLIST; i++)
            node = merge(alist[i], node);
        return node;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks again. You said the `merge` function in the question will take O(n) space, so does that mean that `mergeSort` function O(1) and `merge` makes it O(n)? If I use the `merge` function you provided, will that make the entire Merge Sort O(1) space complexity?

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe - The merge sort code in the question takes O(log(n)) stack space since it's a top down merge sort.

Comment: Shoot, really? I had tried to implement your `sort` code in your answer, however Im having trouble converting from array to linked list. Would you mind helping me.

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe - the example code in my answer already sorts a linked list. The array alist[] is use to store internal working lists during the sort. alist[i] is either null or points to a list with 2 to the power i nodes. If not null, then alist[0] points to a list with 1 node, alist[1] points to a list with 2 nodes, alist[2] points to a list with 4 nodes, alist[3] points to a list with 8 nodes, ... .

Comment: @rcdldr Oh I see. that makes sense. Thanks a lot. So that code you provided uses O(1) space, and to my knowledge, take O(nlogn) time, correct?

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe - correct on both issues, O(1) space, and O(n log(n)) time. It's also faster than the top down method.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Just for curiosity's sake, are there any other implementations of mergesort on linked list which satisfy O(nlog(n)) time and O(1) space complexities?

Comment: @AlonzoRobbe - top down merge sort could be implemented using an array to replace the stack, but a fixed array size implies a maximum list size, and it would be slower than the bottom up approach, The bottom up approach avoids the maximum list size limit by allowing a working list of unlimited size in alist[NUMLIST-1]. From a practical perspective, an array size of 64 would handle any list that could fit in memory on a 64 bit system, so the list size limit is a theoretical issue, not a practical issue.

Comment: @rcgldr why doesnt creating an array in your `sort` costing you space. like how is that 0(1) space?

Comment: @RobBor - O(1) is a bit misleading, since it really means O(1 x constant), but constants and/or lower order terms are ignored. O(1) just means a fixed size space.